# CloudBees credentials SubVersion

Tags: svn, cloudbees

I wonder if you can give permissions to certain Subversion repositories to certain users.

For example, in my account I have created 2 users (USR1 and USR2) and 2 repositories (SVN1 and SVN2) and want the user USR1 only writable and read about the repository SVN1 and repository SVN2 could do nothing.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can with standard Subversion. How to do it with your hosting provider is a question you'll have to ask your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All users into your account will have access to all your repositories. On the cloud only way you can establish this kind of security mechanism is on Jenkins through the RBAC plugin